# How to create the share button?

Tags: java, social-networking, feed

I am creating a social website which displays status feed from user's friends. I want to add one button that when people click it they can share the status to their own status feed and their friends can see the shared item. How to implement that? How to set up the database and queries?

Thanks

Comment: There are quite a few share buttons that you can implement . Facebook share , Twitter share , Google+ share . Which one are you looking it . The codes for each with vary

Comment: I need to create the share button for my own site and know the data structure.

Answer (score 0):

To create a Facebook Page that has the share button you can make use of the

```
href = "http://www.facebook.com/sharer.php?u=<url to be shared>"
```

You may refer to the official documentation for [Facebook Social plugins](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/)

To create the Google+ share button just add the following taken from [Google Developers Documentation](https://developers.google.com/+/web/share/)

```
<!-- Place this tag where you want the share button to render. -->
<div class="g-plus" data-action="share"></div>

<!-- Place this tag after the last share tag. -->
<script type="text/javascript">
  (function() {
    var po = document.createElement('script'); po.type = 'text/javascript'; po.async = true;
    po.src = 'https://apis.google.com/js/plusone.js';
    var s = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; s.parentNode.insertBefore(po, s);
  })();
</script>
```

Note : Both these can be placed directly on the `html` page of you website .